# How to get year and month from a date - PHP

Tags: php, date

How to get year and month from a given date.

e.g.       `$dateValue = '2012-01-05';`

From this date I need to get year as **2012** and month as **January**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38476483/6438706

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$time=strtotime($dateValue);
$month=date("F",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);
```

Comment: Why not `$result = date("F Y",$time);`?

Comment: But I have a question how php is going to differentiate between day and month here?..

Comment: how to display first three letter of month?eg:Feb for February

Answer (score 13):

Using [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/Strtotime) from the docs.

```
$date = "2012-01-05";

$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));

$month = date('F', strtotime($date));

echo $month
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the most efficient code, but here it goes:

```
$dateElements = explode('-', $dateValue);
$year = $dateElements[0];

echo $year;    //2012

switch ($dateElements[1]) {

   case '01'    :  $mo = "January";
                   break;

   case '02'    :  $mo = "February";
                   break;

   case '03'    :  $mo = "March";
                   break;

     .
     .
     .

   case '12'    :  $mo = "December";
                   break;


}

echo $mo;      //January
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using these function to get year, month, day from the date

you should put them in a class

```
    public function getYear($pdate) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
        return $date->format("Y");
    }

    public function getMonth($pdate) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
        return $date->format("m");
    }

    public function getDay($pdate) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
        return $date->format("d");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code:

```
$dateValue = strtotime('2012-06-05');
$year = date('Y',$dateValue);
$monthName = date('F',$dateValue);
$monthNo = date('m',$dateValue);
printf("m=[%s], m=[%d], y=[%s]\n", $monthName, $monthNo, $year);
```

Answer (score 5):

I will share my code:

In your given example date:

```
$dateValue = '2012-01-05';
```

It will go like this:

```
dateName($dateValue);



   function dateName($date) {

        $result = "";

        $convert_date = strtotime($date);
        $month = date('F',$convert_date);
        $year = date('Y',$convert_date);
        $name_day = date('l',$convert_date);
        $day = date('j',$convert_date);


        $result = $month . " " . $day . ", " . $year . " - " . $name_day;

        return $result;
    }
```

and will return a value: **January 5, 2012 - Thursday**

Answer (score 3):

```
$dateValue = '2012-01-05';
$yeararray = explode("-", $dateValue);

echo "Year : ". $yeararray[0];
echo "Month : ". date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $yeararray[1]));
```

Usiong explode() this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dateValue = '2012-01-05';
$year = date('Y',strtotime($dateValue));
$month = date('F',strtotime($dateValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using this shortcut. The output will still be the same, but you don't need to store the month and year in separate variables

```
$dateValue = '2012-01-05';
$formattedValue = date("F Y", strtotime($dateValue));
echo $formattedValue; //Output should be January 2012
```

A little side note on using this trick, you can use comma's to separate the month and year like so:

```
$formattedValue = date("F, Y", strtotime($dateValue));
echo $formattedValue //Output should be January, 2012
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION yii_attendance.DATEPART does not exist The SQL being executed was: SELECT daytime  FROM attendance WHERE DATEPART(month, my_date_field) = 8 ORDER BY daytime DESC`

Answer (score -1):

```
$dateValue = strtotime($q);

$yr = date("Y", $dateValue) ." "; 
$mon = date("m", $dateValue)." "; 
$date = date("d", $dateValue);
```

Comment: This does not convert the month to **January**, you're close though. F should be used, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.