# Calculate months and years from given value in PHP, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Calculate months and years from given value in PHP framework `CodeIgniter`

**EMI calculator:**

[image]

Here I have a total months duration, but I need to find out when is come that month and year in CodeIgniter or PHP format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI code update in date diff

```
 $datetime1 = date_create(date);
 $datetime2 = date_create(date);
 $interval = date_diff($datetime1,$datetime2);
 //echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
 echo $interval->format('%y years %m months %d day basil');
```